How to implement Angular reactive form input validation
Here is my form below: The current error checks in the form are not working.
<div formGroupName="deliveryAddress">
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col mb-4">
        <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <input id="firstName" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" formControlName="firstName"
            (change)="saveToDataStore()">

        <div *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required')">
                First Name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col mb-4">
        <label class="form-label">Last Name</label>
        <input id="lastName" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" formControlName="lastName"
            (change)="saveToDataStore()">

            <div *ngIf="lastName.invalid && (lastName.dirty || lastName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="lastName.hasError('required')">
                    Last Name is required.
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input id="phone" class="form-control fw-bold" type="phone" formControlName="phone"
                (change)="saveToDataStore()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Here is the declaration of the form in the component:
private initCheckoutForm = () => {
this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  deliveryAddress: this.formBuilder.group({ 
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    phone: ['', Validators.required],
    address1: ['', Validators.required],
    address2: [''],
    useAsBillingAddress: [''],
  }),
  applianceDelivery: this.formBuilder.group({ 
      deliveryDate: ['', Validators.required],
      specialInstructions: [''],
  }),
  paymentMethod: this.formBuilder.group({ 
      paymentType: ['', Validators.required],
      cardNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      expMonth: ['', Validators.required],
      expYear: ['', Validators.required],
      CVV: ['', Validators.required],
      defaultCreditCard: [''],
  })
});
    console.log('this.checkoutForm', this.checkoutForm.value);
  }


please share the code used for geting firstName, lastName, etc properties, please share a working example on stackblitz where the issue happens

re-post, no?  Did you check the comments on your original question?

This is absolutely not a repost. It is a new post of the same application. In fact, I solved the previous question that I posted.

unless you have a getters like
get firstName()
{
   return this.checkoutForm.get('deliveryAddress.firstName')
}
..same with the others: lastName, phone,...

You should use this when you check
   <div *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('deliveryAddress.firstName').invalid && 
                  (checkoutForm.get('deliveryAddress.firstName').dirty || 
                   checkoutForm.get('deliveryAddress.firstName').touched)"> 

NOTE: If you only have an unique validator, you can omit check the hasError('required')
Well, it's hard to create several setter or add in .html this hard to read  "ifs" so, why not create a directive?
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName],[formControl]',
  exportAs: 'ngControl',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ControlDirective {
  constructor(@Host() @Optional() private control: NgControl) {}
  get invalid() {
    return this.control?.invalid;
  }
  get touched() {
    return this.control?.touched;
  }
  get dirty() {
    return this.control?.dirty;
  }
  get value() {
    return this.control?.value;
  }
}

Then we can use a template reference variable in the way #variable='ngControl'
e.g.
  form = new FormGroup({
    group: new FormGroup({
      control: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    }),
  });

and use
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formGroupName="group">
      <input #control="ngControl" formControlName="control" />
      @if(control.invalid && control.touched) { invalid }
    </div>
  </form>

a stackblitz
Update Another way to show errors are simply use .css
.error {
  display: none;
}
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty + .error,
.ng-invalid.ng-touched + .error {
  display: block;
}

So, we can write, e.g.
<input [formControl]="controlName">
<div class="error">Required</div>

